# openrowset query and passing data

Tags: sql-server

The following gives me a syntax error (a very non descriptive one). The reason that I am doing it this way is that I eventually want to replace the dates with the values from variables.

```
 DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000) = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (''SQLOLEDB'',''Server=WIN-
T7HOHROSTNT\SQLEXPRESS;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;database = MyDB'',
''SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [MyDB].[dbo].[GetCourseReport]
        @Start = N''22 Jan 2014 4:00pm'',
        @End = N''23 Jan 2014 4:00pm'',
        @QueryTime = N''22 Jan 2014 8:00pm'',
        @CourseSUID = 1'') AS Result'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt = @sql
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).